# Can "not only, ... but also" be used like "either .. or"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> You can reach the place via not only Route A but also Route B.

I created the sentence above to intend that there is no need to use both Route A and Route B to reach the place. Is this usage correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to say that you have two possibilities to reach the place, you can say:

> You can reach the place not only via Route A but also Route B.